# To mimic os variables in my mock test cases

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have two python files, the first python file which is triggered in server will dynamically fetch the variable result based on the environment the script is triggered . for an example , when script is triggered in dev environment. ideally, ${RPM_ENVIRONMENT} will return as 'DEV'

I have two files, one is my main file  and one is my unit test cases

```
import os
import json
import subprocess

import logging
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

_ENV = os.popen("echo ${RPM_ENVIRONMENT}").read().split('\n')[0]

SERVER_URL = {
    'DEV':{'ENV_URL':'https://dev.net'},
    'UAT':{'ENV_URL':'https://uat.net'},
    'PROD':{'ENV_URL':'https://prod.net'}
}[_ENV]
```

inside my test cases script below, i wanted to mimic as dev environment using unitest mock . i have tried below script but it was returning RPM_ENVIROMENT as key error .

test_env.py

```
import unittest , sys , tempfile, os , json , shutil
from unittest import mock

## i wanted to mock all the required variables before running import env_test so that it wont return any error. 
with mock.patch.object(os, 'popen') as mock_popen:
    sys.path.insert(1, 'C:/home/test/conf')
    import env_test as conf

class test_tbrp_case(unittest.TestCase):
    def  test_port(self):
        #function yet to be created
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have tried using os.popen to mimic , but i am confused on how i can assign 'DEV' to _ENV variable .

when i tried to run this script, it was returning error as

```
    SERVER_URL = {
KeyError: <MagicMock name='popen().read().split().__getitem__()' id='1893950325424'
```

**Approach 2 i have tried **
What i am trying to mock is the import , when im importing my main.py , it should dynamically replace/mock _ENV as 'DEV'  , and SERVER_URL variable should automatically call Dev.

In a scenario where i call conf._ENV after i have implemented the mock below. it should return the value as "DEV"

```
def rpm_environment():
    return os.popen("echo ${RPM_ENVIRONMENT}").read()

def test_rpm_environment(): 
    with mock.patch("os.popen") as popen_mock:
        popen_mock().read.return_value = "DEV"
        actual = rpm_environment()
    assert actual == "DEV"


## When i import env_test , RPM_ENVIROMENT wont be able to mock as DEV on what was declared in our test_rpm_enviromnet
rpm_environment()
test_rpm_environment()

# How can we safely import our env_test files with having variables been mocked so that i can call server_url variable 
sys.path.insert(1, 'C:/home/test/conf')
import env_test import conf
```

Comment: Well, you are mocking `os.environ` not the environment variables themselves. And you call bash directly, which doesn't use `os.environ`. So you probably need to mock `os.popen`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych i have tried your suggested suggestion using os.popen , but i was having issues on assigning 'DEV' to _ENV variable.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't quite understand if your code is inside a function or not.
If it is, the best way to do so is not patch.object. It's just a normal patch:

Consider this example:

```
def question():
    return os.popen("what_ever").read()


def test_question():
    with patch("os.popen") as popen_mock:
        popen_mock().read.return_value = "DEV"
        actual = question()
    assert actual == "DEV"
```

In my opinion, patching os.popen and adding read to it's structure is the best practice.

Good luck !

Comment: Hi Nimrod , I have tried your approach and updated the question on this . 
However after importing my env_test file , it was returning error.

Answer (score 0):

When you mock `popen` it will return a `MagickMock` object and that object does not have a defined `read` response. You need to define what happens when someone calls `read()` on a `MagickMock` object that you have returned. Although it is not the most elegant solution, you can do this by adding this line in the `with` block:

```
mock_popen.return_value.read.return_value = "DEV"
```

This will instruct the `MagickMock` object to return the string "DEV" when `read()` is called on it.